# how do I solve Installation failed: There has been a critical error on your website

Tags: plugins, woocommerce-offtopic

I have installed a fresh copy of wordpress. The first thing I did was to install woocommerce plugin. When I clicked on the install plugin option from the add new plugin window it did show that it was being installed but then at last it says there has been a critical error. Not only woocommerce it is happening in all the plugins. I even tried to download the plugin manually and then copied it into yhe wordpress plugin folder but when I tried to activate it, it again gave me the same error. I am currently running on windows 10 and **I also have looked on google but none of the solutions are working.** Please help me solve this.

Comment: Check your PHP version as well as the WordPress version.

Comment: Maybe try an older version of wp? I have the same problem... using infinity host... one account installs it fine the next site refuses to install woo at all.
Go figure ... no idea why this happens, only solutions I can think of is check php version or use an older wp version.

Answer (score -1):

It happens in some minor cases. If you have a fresh WordPress installation, then install and Activate the **[WP Reset](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-reset/)** plugin from **Plugins > Add New**. Head over to **Tools > WP Reset** and then at the end of the page, type on *Reset* in the given box and click on Reset. This will reset your WordPress installation's *database* and some other things.

Similarly, go to other pages of the plugin, and reset all the things back to default by a click. It'll be easy and the issue will go away.

*Tip: This issue happens mostly in new WordPress installations and in some cases in abandoned installations.*

Another alternative method which you can use is the **WordPress Database Repair** function. This function is built-in and will check and repair the installation's database. To do this, you can check the WPBeginner's guide [here](https://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-fix-the-error-establishing-a-database-connection-in-wordpress/).

These solutions worked for me and some other thousands of people so there is a possibility for you also.